# Select picture from gallery function after hitting the 'UPLOAD PICTURE' and display the picture in imageView

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmapimage, android-external-storage

I want to allow user to select a picture from gallery after hitting the 'UPLOAD PICTURE' button but my codes seems to be not working fine. The app crashed right after user select desired picture.

This is my codes for OnCreate in MainActivity:

```
public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 100;
private final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("INSERT ENDPOINT HERE", 
"INSERT API KEY HERE");

    takePicture = findViewById(R.id.takePic);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    hidden = findViewById(R.id.hidden);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    uploadPicture = findViewById(R.id.uploadPic);
    process = findViewById(R.id.processClick);


    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                //IMPORTANT: You may notice that the pictures from the camera are low quality.
                //TO FIX THIS: You need to request permission to write external storage that way you can access the full-quality image
                //from the device, rather than a low quality thumbnail.
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                } else {
                    if (counter == 2 || (counter > 2 && counter % 2 == 0)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } else                         //Requesting storage permissions so we can get a high quality image.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                    counter++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    });

    uploadPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                    intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }


    });

    process.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ready) {
                detectandFrame(mBitmap);
            } else {
                makeToast("Please take a picture.");
            }
        }
    });
   
}
```

This is my onActivityResult in MainActivity:

```
Uri imageUri;
ContentValues values;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100) { //High Quality picture using URI and storage
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = mBitmap;
                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
                int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                switch (orientation) {

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(mBitmap, 90);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(mBitmap, 180);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(mBitmap, 270);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    default:
                        rotatedBitmap = mBitmap;
                }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Error getting high quality image --> Use low quality thumbnail.
                makeToast("Error: " + e.toString());
                //mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                e.printStackTrace();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }
            ready = true;
            hidden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }else if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //Low Quality image
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        ready = true;
        hidden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ready = true;
            hidden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
}

}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml code. I realised that when I include the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest, my Take Picture from camera function does not work after hitting the process button. It will show 'detecting' for quite a while and crashed after. So the result will not be shown. However after I removed the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest, it works fine showing the result. But still the selection from gallery still crashed after user select one picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.anany.emotionrecognition">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/smiling"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/smiling"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResultActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

This is my error log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.anany.emotionrecognition, PID: 30227
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw//storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20201016-WA0028.jpg typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.anany.emotionrecognition/com.example.anany.emotionrecognition.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.anany.emotionrecognition.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:216)
```

Comment: `The app crashed right after user select desired picture.` That would be in onActivityResult then. You posted much too much code. Only this function and the used intent is enough. Post the logcat instead of all that irrelevant code.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.anany.emotionrecognition.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:216)`What is on line 216?

Comment: There is still much too much code.

Comment: `getRealPathFromURI(imageUri)`That function will return `null`. Dont use such a terrible function.

Comment: @blackapps (MainActivity.java:216) is  mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); It is inside the }else if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

Comment: We were not talking about requestCode== 1 but about `user to select a picture from gallery` requestCode==PICK_IMAGE.  `But still the selection from gallery still crashed after user select one picture.` You have too much code outsice onActivityResult()... well for stackoverflow. And too much code inside for stackoverflow. You should post minimal code. You confuse us all.

Comment: @blackapps before I removed my manifest code there. Is there anything wrong with my manifest or anything that I should add in there? Do I need to include WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission or not?

Answer (score 1):

change the `uploadpicture` onclicklistner code

```
uploadPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageFile = getDefaultFileName(MainActivity.this);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE);
        }

 public File getDefaultFileName(Context context) {
        File imageFile1;
        Boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        if (isSDPresent) { // External storage path
            imageFile1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "abc" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        } else {  // Internal storage path
            imageFile1 = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "abc" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        }
        return imageFile1;
    }
```

My updated `onActivityResult`based on your answer

```
Uri imageUri;
ContentValues values;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_IMAGE:
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream =
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    if (inputStream != null)
                        inputStream.close();
                    String imagePath = Uri.fromFile(imageFile).getPath();

                    // Here Add you image load code
                  //  if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                   //     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                   //     String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    //    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    //            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        
                   // }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                ready = true;
                hidden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void copyStream(InputStream input, FileOutputStream output) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check updated comment and please initiate `imageFile` top of activity

Comment: It works fine selecting picture and load but the picture selected doesnt been set to the imageview so it does appear blank for now. how do I set it to the imageView? as you can see from my code up there I have two imageView one is visible and one is hidden. Ive tried putting the imageView lines before the break but nothing seems worked and im not sure what is the image should be set in the imageView, is it the mBitmap?

Comment: It still doesnt work @Deep Parsania I think because of the setVisibility but after I put the code imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   ready = true;
                    hidden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); it still doesnt work

Comment: check your comment @Deep Parsania. I've updated with my latest onActivityResult

Comment: updated comment. I have added a toast message to your imagePath please check what is display in Toast Message

Comment: It still showing just a white screen on the imageview.

Comment: I have added the Toast Message of imagepath. so check what is display in Toast Message

Answer (score 0):

> > ```
> >             ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
> > ```

Change to:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

ExifInterFace ei = new ExifInterFace(is);
```

Comment: Did as your code but still crashed after pick a photo. error log still at  mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");         in the             } else if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

Comment: You confused me with your post with TOO MUCH CODE.